# Set title of navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

So I have a basic view controller with a navigation bar, this is view controller B, so I'm performing a segue to go here, and I'm trying to change the title like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    debugPrint(self.selectedName)
    super.viewDidLoad();
    self.navigationItem.title = "A NEW TITLE"
}
```

But it doesn't do anything

[image]

Comment: can you add your storyboard scene

Comment: Your screen shot is from the storyboard. The code will only affect the screen when you actually run it. Or just update the label directly in the storyboard.

Comment: Is your view controller embedded in a navigation controller or did you simply add a navigation bar object to your view?

Comment: seconded with @xoudini, i think there is another outlet

Comment: @Fogmeister updated

Comment: before the Loading Controller, is there a navigation controller?

Comment: @Uffo your screenshot is still from the storyboard. Run the app. Does it still go wrong?

Comment: @SahebRoy check my updated post please. Thank you

Comment: @Fogmeister yes ofcourse I run it

Comment: @OP is there a navigation controller before the initial VC that we can see?

Comment: @SahebRoy No, thats it! Everything in the image is the whole thing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Swift 3:

If you want to set just the navigation title without using a `UINavigationController` then make an outlet of the navigation item  as

```
 @IBOutlet weak var navItem: UINavigationItem!
```

and then in `viewDidLoad()` write

```
navItem.title = "ANY TITLE"
```

Answer (score 19):

To set Title on NavigationBar simply  we can do by below code

```
self.title = "Your Title"
```

Comment: I have an issue where this Simply doesn't work on iOS 16 building with Xcode 14 cant find any hint of a solution yet.

Answer (score 12):

There are plenty of methods which you can follow to achieve this. Here is few of those.

**First things first.**

If you are ready to "Embed in" a navigation controller or if you have already one then you can access that using following code.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Your Title"
```

**Now for more customization:**

1. Place a `UINavigationBar` object on ViewController scene and add constraints to it.
2. Make an outlet of newly placed `UINavigationBar` like as follows -

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var orderStatusNavigationbar: UINavigationBar!
   ```
3. Now set the title using the outlet.

   ```
   orderStatusNavigationbar.topItem?.title = "Your Title"
   ```

All this above code are in Swift 3 but will work on lower versions of Swift also(atleast on Swift 2.0)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Instead of the accepted answer I used this solution and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 / XCode 10**

1. Add new NavigationBar `->` Drap and Drop it to your view
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to add new Outlet Action
3. Example : `@IBOutlet weak var main_navbar: UINavigationBar` in `ViewController` class.
4. Then set the title : `main_navbar.topItem?.title = "YOUR TITLE"`

This solution worked for me, hope it does for you too. 
- rust[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, 
So you need to embed the whole thing in a Navigation Controller first, and then make that navigation controller as the initial controller.

Select your storyboard, click the first controller then click this -

[image: img]

Then you remove the navigation bar you set(put) over the last controller named "title".

The reason this didnt work, as you are trying to change the title of the navigation controller's navigation bar, but it doesnt have it, hence it cant change it.